# Installing window service on Windows 2003 Can't find Service.InstallState file

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer

I am deploying a windows service which was packaged with the installer (`.msi` and `.exe` files).

Everything worked on my VM, which is installed with `Windows 2003 OS`. But when I went to deploy on the real server, I got the following message (when I doubled-clicked on the msi file and following the installer walk through)

```
Could not find file 
C:\Program Files\ProgramNameFolder\ServiceSetup\Service.InstallState
```

Not sure why the `InstallState` file did not get copied to the folder. I only see the `Service.exe` file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.